# Control may reach end non-void function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The attached code is returning an error:

```
Control may reach end non-void function
```

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        FirstCustomCell *fCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (fCustomCell == nil) {

            fCustomCell = [[FirstCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell"];
        }

        return fCustomCell;

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        SecondCustomCell *sCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (sCustomCell == nil) {

            sCustomCell = [[SecondCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SecondCustomCell"];
        }

        return sCustomCell;

    }
} //<-- Control may reach non-void function (I precise that's the end of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method)
```

I know that the problem is specially at the "return" but how do I eliminate the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You account for the cases where `indexPath.row == 0` and where `indexPath.row == 1` but the compiler is saying: What should I return if the row isn't 0 or 1?

You probably want a `return nil;` at the end of your method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        FirstCustomCell *fCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (fCustomCell == nil) 
        {
            fCustomCell = [[FirstCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell"];
        }
        return fCustomCell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        SecondCustomCell *sCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (sCustomCell == nil) 
        {
            sCustomCell = [[SecondCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"secondCustomCell"];
        }
        return sCustomCell;
    }
    return nil; //<--Add this line
}
```

Or perhaps an "else" case:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        FirstCustomCell *fCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (fCustomCell == nil) 
        {
            fCustomCell = [[FirstCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell"];
        }
        return fCustomCell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        SecondCustomCell *sCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (sCustomCell == nil) 
        {
            sCustomCell = [[SecondCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"secondCustomCell"];
        }
        return sCustomCell;
    }
    else //<--Add this clause
    {
        OtherCustomCell *oCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"otherCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (oCustomCell == nil) 
        {
            oCustomCell = [[OtherCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"otherCustomCell"];
        }
        return sCustomCell;
    }
}
```

---

Note: You also have a typo in your reuse identifiers:

`"secondCustomCell"` is not the same as `"SecondCustomCell"`

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Yes for the "secondCustomCell" that was because of typos when I copy/paste the block of code I have edited little things before ^^

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return nil;` line.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        FirstCustomCell *fCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (fCustomCell == nil) {

            fCustomCell = [[FirstCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"firstCustomCell"];
        }

        return fCustomCell;

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        SecondCustomCell *sCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"secondCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (sCustomCell == nil) {

            sCustomCell = [[SecondCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SecondCustomCell"];
        }

        return sCustomCell;

    }
    return nil;
     }
```

I might add that you need to make sure that you `fCustomCell` and your `sCustomCell` are not (`!=`) `nil`.

```
if (!fCustomCell) {
    fCustomCell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:/*aStyle*/ reuseIdentifier:/*identifier*/];
}
```

The identifier can be a static NSString defined at the beginning of the method like so: `static NSString *identifier = @"cell";`

Look at some tutorials.